# Code to loop through all records in Access using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

i need to check every record in table and if p<> 0 pop up warning with number of record that is not good, im using this code but im getting **error loop without do**

```
Private Sub Command142_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ppp-pd")
Do While rs.EOF = True
rs.MoveFirst
p1 = (Round(rs!brutoprihod - (rs!brutoprihod * rs!ProcPrizTros) - rs!osnovicazaporez))
If p1 = 0 Then
rs.MoveNext
Loop
Else
MsgBox ("not good")
End If
MsgBox ("all records are good")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the If statement cross outside of the loop.  Also, I think your code would only enter the loop if the recordset was empty.  Try this:

```
Private Sub Command142_Click()

    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ppp-pd")

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        p1 = (Round(rs!brutoprihod - (rs!brutoprihod * rs!ProcPrizTros) - rs!osnovicazaporez))
        If p1 <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("not good")
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: i have notice that i make it similar, but dont know how to point in which row is p1 <> 0 in some msgnox

Comment: if you have an id field you could do something like rs!IDField.  Or  `rs.AbsolutePosition + 1` would give you the row number (need to add 1 because it's a zero-based index).